# Visualizing transitions in panel data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

First some toy data:

```
df = read.table(text = 
              "id      year    transition1 transition2 
1           2000    0   1
1           2001    1   0
1           2002    0   0
1           2003    0   0
2           2000    0   0
2           2002    0   0
2           2003    1   1
3           2000    0   0
3           2001    0   0
3           2002    1   0
3           2003    0   1 ", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

I try to visualize in one single plot for each id,

1. if there is an observation in a year (black point)
2. if transition1 occurred  (red point)
3. if transition 2 occurred  (yellow point)

Roughly I know how to visualize the  first step

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=id))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=year), colour="black")
p
```

But how can I add the points for each transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option , Using a nested `ifelse` to create column vector:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=id))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=year), size=10,
                  colour=ifelse(df$transition1==1,"red",
                                ifelse(df$transition2==1,"yellow","black")))
p
```

[image]

Comment: great, thank you. That`s nearly what I was looking for. How can I additionally avoid that one point covers the other? For example, in year 2003, all points should be visible for id 2. (I do not care about the colors if there is a better solution)

Comment: and how do I remove the 1.5 and 2.5 on the y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

To add to @agstudy's answer, try geom_jitter().

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=id)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=year), size=10,
             colour=ifelse(df$transition1==1,"red",
                           ifelse(df$transition2==1,"yellow","black"))) +
  geom_jitter()
```

Comment: @agstudy thank you very much. Does the solution with nested     ifelse also works with more than two transitions? Finally,  is it possible to make the points transparent instead of using jitter?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a slightly different way of going about it that you may or may not find helpful. Essentially it makes a combined variable for both observations. At the moment this will only work for 2 levels but if you need it to work on more levels let me know and I will put a bit of thought into making it work for 3 or more levels.

```
library(ggplot2)

df = read.table(text = 
                  "id      year    transition1 transition2 
1           2000    0   1
1           2001    1   0
1           2002    0   0
1           2003    0   0
2           2000    0   0
2           2002    0   0
2           2003    1   1
3           2000    0   0
3           2001    0   0
3           2002    1   0
3           2003    0   1 ", sep = "", header = TRUE)

# get transition names
trans.names <- names(df[3:4])

# add up the numbers in the data columns
df$total <- apply(df[,c(3:4)], 1, sum)

# for the columns where there is only on transition figure out which type it is
df$total2[which(df$total==1)] <- apply(df[which(df$total==1),c(3:4)], 1, which.max)

#set up the type variable to recieve data
df$type <- ""

# put in the names of the variable where it is one or the other
df$type <- trans.names[df$total2]

# overwrite that data with observation for those ones with no data
df$type[which(df$total==0)] <- "Observation"

# for the ones with both, mark as such
df$type[which(df$total==2)] <- "transition 1 and 2"

# cleanup, remove calculation columns
df <- df[,c("id","year","type")]

# reorder the factors in the 'type' data
df$type <- factor(df$type,levels=c("Observation","transition1", "transition2","transition 1 and 2"))

# make other variables into factors
df$id <- as.factor(df$id)
df$year <- as.factor(df$year)

#plot data
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=id,x=year,color=type)) +
  geom_point(size=10) +
  scale_color_manual(name="Legend Name Goes Here",values=c("black", "red", "yellow","purple"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  ggtitle("Title Goes Here")+
  ylab("y label")+
  xlab("x label")

#show plot
p
```

Hope that is helpful,
Josh